# PHP session and multiple mixed PHP/HTML sections in one page

Tags: php, session

If I have a page with multiple `<?php ...  ?>` sections interspresed with pure HTML sections. I notice that a `$_SESSION` varible set in one `<?php ...  ?>` section is not available in another on the same page.

So, what's the best practise?

1) call `session_start()` as the first line of each `<?php ...  ?>` section?

2) only have one `<?php ...  ?>` section which covers the whole page? If so, I have to wrap each HTML section in `echo`, which is annoying of they are HTML form elements.  Maybe `heredoc` them?

It's my first time to try this sort of thing, but I am not the first one to do so - what's the accepted best practise?

---

Edit:   Aplogies, my stupid fault. One of the sections PHP started with `<?` and not `<?php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I have a page with multiple  sections interspresed with pure
>   HTML sections. I notice that a
>   $_SESSION  varible set in one  section is not available in
>   another on the same page.

The sections of php tags `<?php ... ?>` have nothing to do with session. Make sure that you put:

`session_start()`

on top of your page.

Comment: +! thanks. That was my understanding (from reading,  not actual practise, but it isn't working that way. A single page with 3 PHP sections. Session_start() in the first, set a $_SESSION[] variable in the second, var_dump() in the third and it is null.   Caveat - I am using Xampp and the pages are on lcoalhost - this has given other problems in the past.

Comment: @mawg: o right those are silly but hard to find mistakes sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you set the header before doing any output, you shouldn't have any issues with the session (as the function session_start() also set the header).

There is really no problem having multiple PHP sections on a page. But I would highly recommend, to do all the logic (reading from database, processing form data) in a separate file OR in the first section.

Comment: +1 thanks. AS I said above, it might be an Xampp issue. I will upload to a real website, not localhost, and tgry there.